# PHPUnit test with XAMPP localhost instead of laravel artisan serve

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-dusk

I have unit tests (not dusk browser test) setup on laravel 5.4, I have configured the baseUrl in phpunit.xml  to

> http://localhost/TestApp/public

but when I run

```
vendor\bin\phpunit
```

to assert the status is 200 I get the failed test saying the status returned is 404 while on the browser I can access the URL.

The test is as below

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{

    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicTest()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');


        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

Comment: One hint: `code`

Comment: @Paras updated code

Comment: What's your APP_URL in your .env file?

Comment: @Paras APP_URL=http://localhost/TestApp/public

Comment: though i noted that having the baseUrl to http://localhost:8000 works without artisan serve

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate environment file (.env.testing) for your tests to use localhost/TestApp without /public and it should work.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#environment-configuration