# could not find driver (SQL: PRAGMA writable_schema = 1;)

Tags: laravel, tdd, in-memory-database

I have seen that this question has been asked under different circumstances, so I'm gonna ask it again for my case since I have tried all the answers out there.

I'm trying to  run Unit tests with laravel 8 using in-memory database, and once I enabled in-memory database  I have got the following error:

```
 ! view concert listing test user can view concert listing → This test did not perform any assertions  

D:\laravel\ticketbeast\tests\Unit\tests\Feature\ViewConcertListingTestTest.php:27
   FAIL  Tests\Feature\ViewConcertListingTest
  ⨯ user can view concert listing

  ---

  • Tests\Feature\ViewConcertListingTest > user can view concert listing
    715▕         }
    716▕     }

  1   D:\laravel\ticketbeast\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70 
      PDOException::("could not find driver")

  2   D:\laravel\ticketbeast\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70 
      PDO::__construct()
Tests:  1 failed, 1 risked, 1 passed
  Time:   2.54s
```

I'm using windows 10, Laravel 8, PHP 8, and XAMPP server.
Is anyone familiar with this error using the same configuration?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't have `sql lite` installed... I recommend you to use Docker

Comment: Just to make sure you're using `sqlite` or `mysql`, could you share your `DB_` vars in your env or `.env` file, as well as any relevant config in your `config/database.php` file?

Comment: You may also want to simply use a dedicated test DB as part of your xampp set up, you can do this with a combination of env vars / config file. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50402687/484127), and [this tutorial](https://learn2torials.com/a/laravel8-unit-test-part-1) suggests using a `.env.testing` file with custom db config for your unit tests